# Refuse space only input with ng-required

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-required

Is there a simple way to make inputs and textareas with the `ng-required` attribute set to `true` invalid if it contains only spaces or blank characters ?

I'm looking for a generic way that would be applied to all my fields.

Note : I'm using angular 1.5.5

Comment: create attribute directive.. so that you can reuse it

Comment: Why do you need to use the `ng-required` attribute?

Comment: I don't really get the question here  @MikeMcCaughan I need my input to be required, so I'm using `ng-required`, but I want to make sure that actual data are in that input in order to validate it, that's why I need to refuse blank characters

Comment: As your answer here shows, you don't need to use `ng-required`; that was my question. I wanted to know if you were open to solutions which do not use that specific attribute.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to use the `ng-required` be cause that's the thing in common, and this would have avoided me to do changes in all my files. But I didn't manage to di it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the end I didn't manage to find a generic way.
I had to change every template, but it can be done quickly using the replace option of any IDE.

I replaced every `<textarea` occurences with `<textarea ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\S).+$/"`

So, `ng-pattern` was my solution choice, there's probably a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that you can set "ng-required=checkVar" and all input field you want to be validate in the same way can be put same class (class tag), e.x: class="check". Then you can bind an event handle function to all these fields as:

```
$('.check').on('click', function(e){
    do your work (validating)
    if (validated)
          $scope.checkVar = true;
    else
          $scope.checkVar = false;
}
```

This is my idea.

Comment: You should avoid jQuery event handlers when using AngularJS. Use `ng-click` instead.